# Deploy after commit to git repository in Team Foundation Service

Tags: git, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have a web site in Azure Web Sites and its sources in a git repository under Team Foundation Service.

My goal is to have continuous integration: after each commit to repository I want the code to be built and deployed to Azure.
Unfortunately, this scenario is not supported directly for git (when using TF Source Control under **TFS** one can just tell Azure to do this).

Trying to make a workaround, I have successfully done the following.

1. Perform a build in TFS after each commit.
2. Build and deploy the solution with MSBuild parameters (works when running locally from the command line):

   > msbuild path_to_solution_file /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=publish_profile_name /p:Configuration=Release /p:Password=MyPassword

Is it possible to successfully run the same command in TFS?
I specified the arguments in build definition (Process -> Advanced -> MSBuild Arguments). After any commit, the build is started. According to logs, the arguments are successfully passed to MSBuild. Build succeeds with no errors. But nothing is deployed.

Any ideas how to make it work? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an argument in your MSBuild properties.  Add `/p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0` to your build definition and try again and you should find that it works.

You might also need to supply `/p:UserName=$yourUser`

I've got a [blog post](http://www.richard-banks.org/2013/08/how-to-deploy-azure-website-from-git_21.html) showing how to make it work.